# How can I list a model when it belongs to a another model in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I have two models: Day and Lecture, lecture belongs to day and day has many lectures, I want list all the lecture in each day:

```
<% @days.each do |day| %>
<tr>
  <td><%= day.name %></td>
  <td><%= day.date %></td>
  <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', day_path(day),
                method: :delete,
                data: { confirm: 'This will delete all the lectures in this day. Do you want to continue?' } %></td>


  <br/>
  <%= render @day.lectures %>
  <br/>
</tr>
```

but it does not work with '@day.lectures'.

btw, i already have _lecture.html.erb file and it should be a problem of how to write it. If not, I can put on my routes or more information. Thanks!

Comment: It should be **day.lectures** as your are inside the iterator with **day** variable

Comment: yes, but it is just an example

Comment: What do you mean, doesn't work?

Comment: You should provide a proper error especially if you don't provide the actual code but "just an example"... The error should show you in which directories it tried to find the file which should solve your problem.

Comment: There is no error here..yet. I just do not know how to iterate a model(1) under the iteration of another model(2), and model 1 belongs to model 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `@` from your `@day` instance so that the line is

```
<%= render day.lectures %>
```

You're inside the iteration of `@days` and each day is referenced as `day`

Comment: It is reasonable but when I run it comes out: ActionView::MissingTemplate in Day#index. I already have _lecture.html.erb

Comment: Which file did you write the above code in? And what is the url of the page you are trying to view?

Comment: Above code is in 'day/index.html.erb'; 'lecture/_lecture.html.erb' for render; try to view: localhost:3000/days

Comment: Folders in your view directory should follow be plural: `days/index.html.erb` & `lectures/_lecture.html.erb`. Similar to how your controllers are named (Also plural).